# coord_flip in plot_model sjplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, sjplot

I would appreciate any help in flipping the axis as shown in the picture. I tried using the `coord_flip()` in `plot_model` (sjplot) but without any success . I tried `coord_flip()` / coord_flitp = TRUE but without any success.

[image]

```r
library(sjmisc)
library(sjPlot)

data(efc)
efc <- to_factor(efc, c161sex, e42dep, c172code)
m <- lm(neg_c_7 ~ pos_v_4 + c12hour + e42dep + c172code, data = efc)

# create plot-object
p <- plot_model(m)

# change theme
p + theme_sjplot()
```

[image]

```r
library(lme4)       # linear mixed-effects models
library(lmerTest)   # test for linear mixed-effects models
library(gtsummary)
library(sjPlot)
library(ggplot2)


m1 <- lmer(distance ~ as.factor(year) + (1 | id), data = trajectories)

summary(m1)
p <- plot_model(m1)
p+coord_cartesian()

m2 <- lmer(distance ~ as.factor(year)+sex + (1 | id), data = trajectories)

summary(m2)
p2 <- plot_model(m2, rm.terms = c("sex [M]"))
p2+coord_cartesian()

p3 <- plot_models(m1,m2, rm.terms = c("sex [M]"),
                  axis.labels = c("2010","2009","2008","20007","2006", "2005","2004","2003","2002"))
p3+coord_cartesian()


p4 <- plot_models(m1,m2, rm.terms = c("sex [M]"),
                  axis.labels = c("2002","2003","2004","2005","2006", "2007","2008","2009","2010"))
p4+coord_cartesian()
```

here is output from p3
[image]

here is output from p4

[image]

here is dummy data

```
> dput(trajectories)
structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L), year = c(2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 
2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 
2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2001L, 2002L, 
2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2001L, 
2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 
2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 
2010L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2001L, 2002L, 
2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2004L, 
2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 
2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2001L, 2002L, 
2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2001L, 
2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 
2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 
2010L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 
2009L, 2010L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 
2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 
2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 
2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 
2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 
2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2001L, 2002L, 
2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L), distance = c(15, 
20, 21.5, 23, 21, 21.5, 24, 25.5, 20.5, 24, 21, 20, 21.5, 23, 
21, 21.5, 24, 25.5, 20.5, 24, 21, 20, 21.5, 23, 21, 21.5, 24, 
25.5, 20.5, 24, 21, 20, 21.5, 23, 21, 21.5, 24, 25.5, 20.5, 24, 
21, 20, 21.5, 23, 21, 21.5, 24, 25.5, 20.5, 24, 21, 20, 21.5, 
23, 21, 21.5, 21, 20, 21.5, 23, 21, 21.5, 24, 25.5, 20.5, 24, 
23, 21, 21.5, 24, 25.5, 20.5, 24, 15, 20, 21.5, 23, 21, 21.5, 
24, 25.5, 20.5, 24, 15, 20, 21.5, 23, 21, 21.5, 24, 25.5, 20.5, 
24, 15, 20, 21.5, 23, 21, 21.5, 24, 25.5, 20.5, 24, 15, 20, 21.5, 
23, 21, 21.5, 24, 25.5, 20.5, 24, 15, 20, 21.5, 23, 21, 21.5, 
24, 25.5, 20.5, 24, 15, 20, 21.5, 23, 21, 21.5, 24, 25.5, 20.5, 
24, 15, 20, 21.5, 23, 21, 21.5, 24, 25.5, 20.5, 24, 15, 20, 21.5, 
23, 21, 21.5, 24, 25.5, 20.5, 24, 15, 20, 21.5, 23, 21, 21.5, 
24, 25.5, 20.5, 24, 15, 20, 21.5, 23, 21, 21.5, 24, 25.5, 20.5, 
24, 15, 20, 21.5, 23, 21, 21.5, 24, 25.5, 20.5, 24), age = c(8L, 
9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 
22L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
13L, 14L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 18L, 
19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 28L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 
46L, 47L, 48L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 
28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 
31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 
34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 
37L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 28L, 29L, 
30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 
33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 
36L, 37L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L), 
    Quintile = structure(c(5L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 
    5L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 
    3L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 
    4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 
    5L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 
    2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    5L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 
    2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    5L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 
    2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    5L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 
    2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 5L), levels = c("Q1", "Q2", 
    "Q3", "Q4", "Q5"), class = "factor"), sex = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L), levels = c("F", "M"), class = "factor"), yr_qun = structure(c(6L, 
    8L, 14L, 18L, 21L, 26L, 32L, 35L, 43L, 48L, 2L, 10L, 13L, 
    20L, 23L, 27L, 31L, 37L, 41L, 46L, 2L, 9L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    30L, 37L, 39L, 47L, 4L, 8L, 16L, 18L, 23L, 28L, 31L, 34L, 
    42L, 46L, 5L, 7L, 15L, 19L, 24L, 25L, 33L, 35L, 40L, 45L, 
    4L, 11L, 14L, 18L, 23L, 25L, 4L, 7L, 12L, 20L, 21L, 28L, 
    29L, 36L, 40L, 47L, 17L, 22L, 28L, 33L, 36L, 41L, 44L, 3L, 
    8L, 14L, 17L, 21L, 27L, 33L, 38L, 40L, 48L, 3L, 8L, 14L, 
    17L, 21L, 27L, 33L, 38L, 40L, 48L, 3L, 8L, 14L, 17L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 38L, 40L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 14L, 17L, 21L, 27L, 33L, 38L, 
    40L, 48L, 1L, 1L, 14L, 17L, 21L, 27L, 33L, 38L, 40L, 48L, 
    1L, 1L, 14L, 17L, 21L, 27L, 33L, 38L, 40L, 48L, 1L, 1L, 14L, 
    17L, 21L, 27L, 33L, 38L, 40L, 48L, 1L, 1L, 14L, 17L, 21L, 
    27L, 33L, 38L, 40L, 48L, 1L, 1L, 14L, 17L, 21L, 27L, 33L, 
    38L, 40L, 48L, 1L, 1L, 14L, 17L, 21L, 27L, 33L, 38L, 40L, 
    48L, 1L, 1L, 14L, 17L, 21L, 27L, 33L, 38L, 40L, 48L), levels = c("", 
    "2001_Q1", "2001_Q2", "2001_Q3", "2001_Q4", "2001_Q5", "2002_Q1", 
    "2002_Q2", "2002_Q3", "2002_Q4", "2002_Q5", "2003_Q1", "2003_Q2", 
    "2003_Q3", "2003_Q4", "2003_Q5", "2004_Q1", "2004_Q3", "2004_Q4", 
    "2004_Q5", "2005_Q2", "2005_Q3", "2005_Q4", "2005_Q5", "2006_Q1", 
    "2006_Q2", "2006_Q3", "2006_Q4", "2007_Q1", "2007_Q2", "2007_Q3", 
    "2007_Q4", "2007_Q5", "2008_Q1", "2008_Q2", "2008_Q3", "2008_Q4", 
    "2008_Q5", "2009_Q1", "2009_Q2", "2009_Q3", "2009_Q4", "2009_Q5", 
    "2010_Q1", "2010_Q2", "2010_Q3", "2010_Q4", "2010_Q5"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-183L))
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to rearrange the values on the flipped x axis using `plot_models()`, you can 'pass in' your data in a different order, e.g.

```r
library(sjPlot)
library(ggplot2)
library(forcats)
library(lme4)       # linear mixed-effects models
#> Loading required package: Matrix
# install.packages("lmerTest")
library(lmerTest)   # test for linear mixed-effects models
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lmerTest'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:lme4':
#> 
#>     lmer
#> The following object is masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     step
library(gtsummary)

trajectories <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L),
                               year = c(2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L),
                               distance = c(15, 20, 21.5, 23, 21, 21.5, 24, 25.5, 20.5, 24, 21, 20, 21.5, 23, 21, 21.5, 24, 25.5, 20.5, 24, 21, 20, 21.5, 23, 21, 21.5, 24, 25.5, 20.5, 24, 21, 20, 21.5, 23, 21, 21.5, 24, 25.5, 20.5, 24, 21, 20, 21.5, 23, 21, 21.5, 24, 25.5, 20.5, 24, 21, 20, 21.5, 23, 21, 21.5, 21, 20, 21.5, 23, 21, 21.5, 24, 25.5, 20.5, 24, 23, 21, 21.5, 24, 25.5, 20.5, 24, 15, 20, 21.5, 23, 21, 21.5, 24, 25.5, 20.5, 24, 15, 20, 21.5, 23, 21, 21.5, 24, 25.5, 20.5, 24, 15, 20, 21.5, 23, 21, 21.5, 24, 25.5, 20.5, 24, 15, 20, 21.5, 23, 21, 21.5, 24, 25.5, 20.5, 24, 15, 20, 21.5, 23, 21, 21.5, 24, 25.5, 20.5, 24, 15, 20, 21.5, 23, 21, 21.5, 24, 25.5, 20.5, 24, 15, 20, 21.5, 23, 21, 21.5, 24, 25.5, 20.5, 24, 15, 20, 21.5, 23, 21, 21.5, 24, 25.5, 20.5, 24, 15, 20, 21.5, 23, 21, 21.5, 24, 25.5, 20.5, 24, 15, 20, 21.5, 23, 21, 21.5, 24, 25.5, 20.5, 24, 15, 20, 21.5, 23, 21, 21.5, 24, 25.5, 20.5, 24),
                               age = c(8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 28L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L),
                               Quintile = structure(c(5L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 5L),
                                                      levels = c("Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4", "Q5"), class = "factor"), sex = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L),
                                                                                                                                   levels = c("F", "M"), class = "factor"), yr_qun = structure(c(6L, 8L, 14L, 18L, 21L, 26L, 32L, 35L, 43L, 48L, 2L, 10L, 13L, 20L, 23L, 27L, 31L, 37L, 41L, 46L, 2L, 9L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 30L, 37L, 39L, 47L, 4L, 8L, 16L, 18L, 23L, 28L, 31L, 34L, 42L, 46L, 5L, 7L, 15L, 19L, 24L, 25L, 33L, 35L, 40L, 45L, 4L, 11L, 14L, 18L, 23L, 25L, 4L, 7L, 12L, 20L, 21L, 28L, 29L, 36L, 40L, 47L, 17L, 22L, 28L, 33L, 36L, 41L, 44L, 3L, 8L, 14L, 17L, 21L, 27L, 33L, 38L, 40L, 48L, 3L, 8L, 14L, 17L, 21L, 27L, 33L, 38L, 40L, 48L, 3L, 8L, 14L, 17L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 38L, 40L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 14L, 17L, 21L, 27L, 33L, 38L, 40L, 48L, 1L, 1L, 14L, 17L, 21L, 27L, 33L, 38L, 40L, 48L, 1L, 1L, 14L, 17L, 21L, 27L, 33L, 38L, 40L, 48L, 1L, 1L, 14L, 17L, 21L, 27L, 33L, 38L, 40L, 48L, 1L, 1L, 14L, 17L, 21L, 27L, 33L, 38L, 40L, 48L, 1L, 1L, 14L, 17L, 21L, 27L, 33L, 38L, 40L, 48L, 1L, 1L, 14L, 17L, 21L, 27L, 33L, 38L, 40L, 48L, 1L, 1L, 14L, 17L, 21L, 27L, 33L, 38L, 40L, 48L), levels = c("", "2001_Q1", "2001_Q2", "2001_Q3", "2001_Q4", "2001_Q5", "2002_Q1", "2002_Q2", "2002_Q3", "2002_Q4", "2002_Q5", "2003_Q1", "2003_Q2", "2003_Q3", "2003_Q4", "2003_Q5", "2004_Q1", "2004_Q3", "2004_Q4", "2004_Q5", "2005_Q2", "2005_Q3", "2005_Q4", "2005_Q5", "2006_Q1", "2006_Q2", "2006_Q3", "2006_Q4", "2007_Q1", "2007_Q2", "2007_Q3", "2007_Q4", "2007_Q5", "2008_Q1", "2008_Q2", "2008_Q3", "2008_Q4", "2008_Q5", "2009_Q1", "2009_Q2", "2009_Q3", "2009_Q4", "2009_Q5", "2010_Q1", "2010_Q2", "2010_Q3", "2010_Q4", "2010_Q5"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -183L))

trajectories$year1 <- factor(trajectories$year)

m1 <- lmer(distance ~ year1 + (1 | id), data = trajectories)
m2 <- lmer(distance ~ year1 + sex + (1 | id), data = trajectories)
#> boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular')

trajectories$year2 <- factor(trajectories$year, levels = c("2010","2009","2008","2007","2006", "2005","2004","2003","2002", "2001", "2000"))

m3 <- lmer(distance ~ year2 + (1 | id), data = trajectories)
m4 <- lmer(distance ~ year2 + sex + (1 | id), data = trajectories)
#> boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular')

plot_models(m1,m2) +
  coord_cartesian() +
  theme(legend.position = "top")
#> Coordinate system already present. Adding new coordinate system, which will
#> replace the existing one.
```

[image]

```r
plot_models(m3,m4) +
  coord_cartesian() +
  theme(legend.position = "top")
#> Coordinate system already present. Adding new coordinate system, which will
#> replace the existing one.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: @Jared_mmrot, the variable that I flipped is the year which is on the x-axis now that is what i was looking for. is it possible to reverse the order of this variable currently it is in descending order. I want this to be in ascending order. thank you so much for all your help

Comment: @ Jared_mmrot, i tried order.terms = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6,7,8,9)) but it didnt work for me.

Comment: could this be due to using plot_models? as i am joining two models in the plot. and this function (order.terms) is only for plot_model.

Comment: @i found this https://github.com/strengejacke/sjPlot/issues/452

Comment: @ jared_mamrot, thanks for your help. I want to reorder the x-axis in plot_models.

Comment: thanks for your help. i added a new picture where I would like to reorder the x-axis year variable.

Comment: I cleaned up my answer; does this solve your problem @skpak?

Comment: thanks for the edit. yes it did change the axis label but only the axis label not estimate in plot.

Comment: Did you change the order of the variables? I.e. look at fit1 vs fit4 (same models, different variable order, different order when plotted)

Comment: I have only one variable which is the year which has 9 categories (2002- 2010), which I am interested to order in ascending order. it is a factor variable

Comment: i added my code and the dummy data in the question

Comment: Thanks for updating your question ; the plots don't 'line up' in my example (not sure why) but this is as far as I got with your problem. Sorry I can't be more help. Hope you figure it out!

Comment: @ Jared_mmrot,  sorry i forget to remove sex variable from the model as i only wanted year in the plot. so i updated the model p2 <- plot_model(m2, rm.terms = c("sex [M]"))